# Unable capture event.which || event.keyCode ||event.charCode in Salesfroce Mobile app LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, salesforce-mobile-app

Unable capture event.which || event.keyCode ||event.charCode in Salesfroce Mobile app LWC[image]